# Change 2 color to one/separate art (Illustrator CC2015 or Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Ok, I have art from a customer. They want it printed in one color. When I trace the logos to separate the art they come out terrible. How can I fix this? They just send me a PDF. Do I need to request better art?

[image: After trace]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the source file and the result that you are currently getting? That way we will be able to suggest a better route.

Comment: Are you a print shop or a designer?

Comment: @Ryan yes, this is being printed on envelopes

Comment: @Chris I am extremely new to this site. How do I share my screen shots??

Comment: @JillOkie: you can [edit] your question, then choose the image icon and then just upload your image and add it (PS: just click 'edit' in the previous sentence to edit your question)

Comment: Okay. On the left is the trace image.. on the right is an original image. There is 3 images total. I lose the" INC" when I trace the images too.

Comment: You need a much higher resolution photo to do an image trace for decent results. I would ask your client if they can give you a higher resolution image or a vector version of their logo if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry I am struggling to understand your personal role in this. Do you work at a print shop? Can't you just print it specifying to only use Black Ink?

Comment: @Ryan not sure why my role in this was important. I needed the art to be done digitally. I am prepress graphics. The plates I print for the pressman need to be color separated. I needed to proof the customer for the final and make the printing plate. My purpose of asking this question was to try and complete the task without having to ask for different art files. As soon as I got the PNG files it was a piece of cake! :)

Comment: Thank you everyone!! I appreciate all the help. The simple solution was to get the PNG/JPEG files from the customer. When I traced that it came out beautiful.

Comment: Jill, I'm not trying to be mean. I'm trying to help you. In your comment to me you said, "The plates I print for the pressman need to be color separated." That should really have been in your original question. We had no idea what exactly the issue was, some even flagged your question to be closed as Unclear (once you earn a bit more rep you'll be able to vote like this as well). I have limited knowledge over what you're doing now that I know what it is, but I don't think you need to Image Trace anything. You can do Color Separations within Photoshop from any image.

Comment: @Ryan I'm sorry I kind of took it that way. Its so hard to tell a person's  tones through text. I have very limited knowledge of photoshop. I have the program, but have never used it. I briefly tried to play around with it in Photoshop but I just didn't have the time to find the right tutorial. This post was my first try at using this site as well. At least I gained some experience on what kind of information to include  when asking another question. Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate it. Maybe you can suggest a video or article for Photoshop

Answer (score 1):

The font looks like Helvetica Black Oblique (with tight kerning) and Helvetica Ultra Light Oblique. Why don't you just retype it over the pixelated version (in Adobe) and try to trace it to match?

Answer (score 0):

Open the PDF with Illustrator. If it was vector when they saved it as a PDF it should open fine and be editable in AI. Did you try that yet?

Comment: Yes that was the problem they sent a PDF file to me that was all different colors. Needed to be all black. Was not vectored. I just had to request the PNG file. Image trace in illustrator worked perfectly after that. Thank you though. This order has come and gone! You guys are awesome here!!